# how should I start working with neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am working with graph database and I want to start with neo4j. but i don't know how to     start. which editor I should use for it? (ex. netbeans)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should start with this URL: [Neo4j learn](http://www.neo4j.org/learn). Choose whatever IDE you like: eclipse, netbeans, intellij, ...